# Django Show Unique List Of Subjects (Many To Many) In Dropdown Menu

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I want to be able to produce a dropdown menu in my template with a unique list of subjects.

Subjects are populated inside of admin rather than hard coding them in SUBJECT_CHOICES.

A course can have many subjects or only 1 subject. For example:

Course Title = Django
Subject = Technology

Course Title = Python
Subject = Technology

Course Title = Accounting
Subject = Business

Course Title = E-commerce
Subject(s) = Technology, Business

CourseListView corresponds to the course_list.html template.

`models.py`:

```
class Subject(models.Model):
    SUBJECT_CHOICES = ()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20,choices=SUBJECT_CHOICES, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Course(models.Model):
​
    SKILL_LEVEL_CHOICES = (
        ('Beginner', 'Beginner'),
        ('Intermediate', 'Intermediate'),
        ('Advanced', 'Advanced'),
    )
​
    slug = models.SlugField()
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    description = models.TextField()
    allowed_memberships = models.ManyToManyField(Membership)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    subjects = models.ManyToManyField(Subject)
    skill_level = models.CharField(max_length=20,choices=SKILL_LEVEL_CHOICES, null=True)
    visited_times = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('courses:detail', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})

    @property
    def lessons(self):
        return self.lesson_set.all().order_by('position')
```

​
`views.py`:

```
class CourseListView(ListView):
    model = Course
    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = super().get_queryset()
        title_contains_query = self.request.GET.get('title_contains')
        view_count_min = self.request.GET.get('view_count_min')
        view_count_max = self.request.GET.get('view_count_max')
        date_min = self.request.GET.get('date_min')
        date_max = self.request.GET.get('date_max')
        skill_level_query = self.request.GET.get('skill_level')
        if title_contains_query:
            qs = qs.filter(title__icontains=title_contains_query)
        if view_count_min:
            qs = qs.filter(visited_times__gte=view_count_min)
        if view_count_max:
            qs = qs.filter(visited_times__lte=view_count_max)
        if date_min:
            qs = qs.filter(created_at__gte=date_min)
        if date_max:
            qs = qs.filter(created_at__lte=date_max)
        if skill_level_query:
            qs = qs.filter(skill_level=skill_level_query)
        return qs
```

Desired Output:

[image]

I tried writing a for loop in my template that does return the subjects successfully but they are not unique or showing only once.

```
{% for item in object_list %}
<h2>{{ item.subjects.all}}</h2>
<ul>
    {% for sub in item.subjects.all %}
    <li><a href="#" id="">{{ sub.name }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endfor %}
```

​
Result:
​

```
<QuerySet [<Subject: Business>]>
Business
<QuerySet [<Subject: Technology>]>
Technology
<QuerySet [<Subject: Technology>]>
Technology
<QuerySet [<Subject: Business>]>
Business
```

I would prefer to do it with a for loop that produces unique results, but maybe it can be done with django-select2 or use a form with model select or multiple model select? Can someone provide some code for either the loop or one of these methods?

I would appreciate any help with this.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow _ With reference your statement "_I tried writing a for loop in my template_"; please add any code to your post that you have tried. Even if it didn't produce the expected result, it will likely be a good starting point for other contributors to assist you. Please read the FAQ on creating a Minimal Reproducible Example of code for guidelines >>> https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

I see two solutions here:

The first one if to simply get all the entered values in the `Subject` model but you couldn't use all the filters you are using in your view, only the one about the title.

To do so, just use:

```py
title_contains_query = self.request.GET.get('title_contains')
if title_contains_query:
    subjects = [title for title in Subject.objects.filter(title__icontains=title_contains_query)]
```

The other option is to use the [`distinct()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#distinct) method on your QuerySet which filters and remove the duplicate entries in it. Use it like this: `qs = qs.distinct()`

Hope it helps!

Comment: where would I put your code? In the the Subject class in models.py or in the CourseListView class? How would the for loop change after using your code? Can you use dpaste or something else to help me combine your answer with my code either using the first method or the distinct one?

Comment: both solutions would be put inside the `CourseListView` class, inside the `get_queryset` method, but I can't be sure because I think you haven't put all the code the class. Could you add what's left, or at least the `get` and/or `post` (whichever one is useful)?